# fnpct package in TeX Live 2017 not working

Tags: bugs, fnpct

Does the newest fnpct package have a bug in it? The following works with (the frozen version of) TeX Live 2016 but not with  TeX Live 2017

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}
The cow jumped\footnote{over the moon}.
\end{document}
```

After loading `texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl`, it complains

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@trnslt@ifstrequal #1#2->\ifnum \pdf@strcmp 
                                             {\unexpanded {#1}}{\unexpanded ...
                                         {\unexpanded {#1}}{\unexpanded ..."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bug not in `fnpct` but in `translations`, which it loads. The latter uses `\pdf@strcmp` from `pdftexcmds` but does not explicitly load it. You can therefore fix with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\begin{document}
The cow jumped\footnote{over the moon}.
\end{document}
```

(Likely this happens as in the past `pdftexcmds` was loaded by a number of packages, including `expl3` and the pdfTeX graphics driver. That code has been cleaned up, which exposes any implicit dependencies.)